# How to set '/' path in react ssr settings

Tags: reactjs

```js
app.use(express.static('bundle File Path'));
```

Hi guys
I'm configuring SSR with react

When entering the '/' path,
Data does not come with express get function
blocked in express static function

Please advise on how to with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is a file named index in the static file registration path, you cannot access it with '/'.

Therefore, when bundled, the names of html files or other files must not start with index.